# Удалить несколько элементов ассоц. массива с условием и поставить в начале другого массива

Tags: php

Есть несколько массивов. Ваше вниманию несколько из них (на примере тв-программы):

```
Array

(
[09:10] => Х/ф "Видимость гнева" 16+
[11:35] => Х/ф "Охотники на троллей" 16+
[13:45] => Х/ф "Сеть" 16+
[16:05] => Х/ф "Маска" 12+
[18:15] => Х/ф "Лица в толпе" 16+
[20:15] => Х/ф "Разум и чувства" 12+
[23:10] => Х/ф "Джерри Магуайер" 16+
[02:00] => Х/ф "Последний самурай" 16+
[05:00] => Х/ф "Сёстры Магдалины" 16+
[07:10] => Х/ф "Одноклассники" 16+
)
Array
(
[09:10] => Х/ф "Кит" 16+
[11:05] => Х/ф "Последний самурай" 16+
[14:05] => Х/ф "Джерри Магуайер" 16+
[16:50] => Х/ф "Одноклассники" 16+
[18:55] => Х/ф "Кит" 16+
[20:50] => Х/ф "Сёстры Магдалины" 16+
[23:10] => Х/ф "Октябрьское небо" 12+
[01:15] => Х/ф "Унесённые ветром" 12+
[05:15] => Х/ф "Холод в июле" 16+
[07:05] => Х/ф "Улыбка Моны Лизы" 12+
)
```

Первый — это понедельник (`$monday`), второй — вторник (`$tuesday`). Мне нужно каждый элемент в конце массива, который больше или равен 07:00 и меньше `$main_key` (`$main_key` — это первое время '09:10'), поставить в начале следующего дня.

Как это сделать в таком ассоциативном массиве? Как, например, `ksort` понимает, что 07:00 меньше, чем 09:10, — я к тому, что если я просто применю `ksort`, скажем, к `$monday`, то он выведет по возрастанию:

```
Array
(
[02:00] => Х/ф "Последний самурай" 16+
[05:00] => Х/ф "Сёстры Магдалины" 16+
[07:10] => Х/ф "Одноклассники" 16+
[09:10] => Х/ф "Видимость гнева" 16+
[11:35] => Х/ф "Охотники на троллей" 16+
[13:45] => Х/ф "Сеть" 16+
[16:05] => Х/ф "Маска" 12+
[18:15] => Х/ф "Лица в толпе" 16+
[20:15] => Х/ф "Разум и чувства" 12+
[23:10] => Х/ф "Джерри Магуайер" 16+
)
```

Как-то же `ksort` понял, что ключи, которые меньше [09:10], должны стоять раньше...

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял

```
$in=[$monday, $tuesday, $wednesday, ....];
$out=[];

$current=0;
$lastTime='';
foreach($in as $day){
    foreach($day as $time => $film){
        if($time >= '09:10' && $lastTime < '09:10') $current++;
        $out[$current][$time] = $film;
        $lastTime = $time;
    }
}
```

[sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c5ce5c88e60c031e6dab510b4a2bcc9dcaee7b9)

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вариант достаточно хорошо. С $current++ необычно придумано. Вот что получается из Вашего ответа:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [09:10] => Х/ф "Искупление" 16+
        [11:45] => Х/ф "Робин Гуд: Мужчины в трико" 12+
        [14:00] => Х/ф "Это очень забавная история" 16+
        [16:05] => Х/ф "Лабиринт Фавна" 16+
        [18:35] => Х/ф "Голубая лагуна" 16+
        [20:50] => Х/ф "Возвращение в Голубую лагуну" 16+
        [23:10] => Х/ф "Господин Никто" 12+
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [01:55] => Х/ф "Патриот" 16+
        [05:05] => Х/ф "Экстрасенс" 16+
        [06:55] => Х/ф "Народ против Ларри Флинта" 16+
        [09:10] => Х/ф "Прости за любовь" 16+
        [11:40] => Х/ф "Патриот" 16+
...
```

То есть, все, что после 00:00 переходит в следующий день. Но мне нужно немного иначе. Чтобы следующий день начинался с времени предыдущего дня. Вот так.

Было:

```
Array
(
[09:10] =>  Прости за любовь
[11:40] =>  Патриот
[15:00] =>  Господин Никто
[17:50] =>  Народ против Ларри Флинта
[20:35] =>  Прости за любовь
[23:10] =>  B ожидании вечности
[01:05] =>  Дракула
[03:30] =>  День сурка
[05:20] =>  Вне/себя
[07:15] =>  Тихая гавань
)
Array
(
[09:10] =>  Уж кто бы говорил 2
[10:45] =>  Дракула
```

Стало:

```
Array
(
[09:10] =>  Прости за любовь
[11:40] =>  Патриот
[15:00] =>  Господин Никто
[17:50] =>  Народ против Ларри Флинта
[20:35] =>  Прости за любовь
[23:10] =>  B ожидании вечности
[01:05] =>  Дракула
[03:30] =>  День сурка
[05:20] =>  Вне/себя

)
Array
(
[07:15] =>  Тихая гавань
[09:10] =>  Уж кто бы говорил 2
[10:45] =>  Дракула
```

То есть, только 07:15 перешло в следующий день (из условия было более 07:00, но меньше $main_key = '09:10')

Comment: поправил условие

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял зачем вообще переменная $lastTime=''... Я немного подкорректировал:

```
$in = array($monday, $tuesday, $wednesday, $thursday, $friday, $saturday, $sunday);
$out = array();

$current = 0;
foreach($in as $day){
    foreach($day as $time => $film){
        if($time >= '07:00' && $time < $main_key){ 
            $current++;
        }
        $out[$current][$time] = $film;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($out);
echo '</pre>';
```

Но получается один неприятный момент. Если между 07:00 и 09:10 только один элемент, то все работает, как часы, - $out состоит из 8 элементов (от 0 до 7, где последний [7] - массив из одной строки после воскресенья, это нормально). Но допустим, если между 07:00 и 09:10 есть более одного элемента (скажем, два). То массивов становится больше восьми из-за current++. 
Привожу пример:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [10:00] => Знакомство с орангутангами
        [10:25] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
        [11:15] => В дебрях Африки
        [12:10] => Неизведанный Индокитай
        [13:05] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [14:00] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
        [14:55] => Полиция Филадельфии - отдел по защите животных
        [15:50] => В дебрях Африки
        [16:45] => Крупный улов
        [17:40] => Неизведанный Индокитай
        [18:35] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [19:30] => Крупный улов
        [20:25] => Полиция Хьюстона - отдел по защите животных
        [21:20] => Правосудие Техаса
        [22:15] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [23:10] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
        [00:05] => Полиция Хьюстона - отдел по защите животных
        [01:00] => Правосудие Техаса
        [01:55] => В дебрях Латинской Америки
        [02:50] => Крупный улов
        [03:45] => Полиция Филадельфии - отдел по защите животных
        [04:40] => Полиция Хьюстона - отдел по защите животных
        [05:35] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [06:25] => В дебрях Латинской Америки
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [07:15] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [08:02] => Крупный улов
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [08:49] => Правосудие Техаса
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [09:36] => Знакомство с орангутангами
        [10:25] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
        [11:15] => Полиция Хьюстона - отдел по защите животных
        [12:10] => В дебрях Латинской Америки
        [13:05] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [14:00] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
        [14:55] => Полиция Филадельфии - отдел по защите животных
        [15:50] => Правосудие Техаса
        [16:45] => Крупный улов
        [17:40] => В дебрях Латинской Америки
        [18:35] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [19:30] => Речные монстры: логово гигантов
        [20:25] => Спасение собак
        [21:20] => Защитники животных
        [22:15] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [23:10] => Доктор Ди: ветеринар Аляски
        [00:05] => Спасение собак
        [01:00] => Защитники животных
        [01:55] => В дебрях Латинской Америки
        [02:50] => Речные монстры: логово гигантов
        [03:45] => Полиция Филадельфии - отдел по защите животных
        [04:40] => Защитники животных
        [05:35] => Аквариумный бизнес
        [06:25] => В дебрях Латинской Америки
    )
```

Здесь в роли $main_key идет 10:00. И получается, что после 07:00 и до 10:00 есть еще 3 элемента, которые сами по себе...